# Redux: Does it make sense to have successReducer and errorReducer to centralize http response management?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, mern

I have followed a tutorial that centralizes React app error management with Redux in an errorReducer file:

> errorReducer.js

```
import { GET_ERRORS } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {};
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ERRORS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

That way, whenever there's an error in any http request, the content of the error is stored only in one place in the app:

> authActions.js

```
export const registeruser = (userData, history) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/register", userData)
    .then((res) => {
      history.push("/login-page");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data,
      });
    });
};
```

And this is how the error response is managed in `Register` component:

> RegisterPage.js

```
export class RegisterPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      errors: {},
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <div>
          {Object.values(errors).map((value) => (
            <p>{value}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

RegisterPage.propTypes = {
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  errors: state.errors,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { registeruser })(
  withRouter(RegisterPage)
);
```

*#NOTE: I only displayed the code that is relevant to error management.*

The same logic is applied for all components.
Sometimes, I would like to display a text when a request is succesful and not necessarily perform an action like the one above:

```
history.push("/login-page");
```

What I would like to know is:
Does it make sense to create a success reducer, similar to the error reducer, that I can use to centralize the logic to be executed when any http request has been successful inside React components and display a message accordingly.

Comment: you could be executing more than one async-action at the same time ... then you wouldn't know your success-flag belongs to what action ... I'd say it's safe to have success-flag per action

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli But, I believe I can have one single reducer to manage success props in the app. I do agree however that I should have one success-flag per action.

Comment: My personal opinion, all approaches are good (centralized, or success-per-reducer) as long as you're not making **global-success-flag** for all of your actions ...

Comment: Great, that makes sense. I believe the tutorial I used has followed a wrong approach by using a global-error-flag.